# XCM transfer of ROC from parachain to Rococo does not update balance on Rococo

Tags: xcm, error, transfer

I am currently successfully able to transfer ROC from Rococo to a parachain using a **Reserve Asset Transfer**. However when I want to transfer some of the ROC from our parachain back to Rococo but when I use ReserveAssetTransfer the following happens

- The asset balance gets reduced for the account but the total balance on the parachain stays the same (I assume it is stored on a Sovereign Account)
- **Message seems to be processed successfully on both the parachain and Rococo but the ROC balance on Rococo has not been updated**

A similar issue occurs when I am trying to **Teleport** the asset - the balance on Rococo does not update but the balance on the parachain is burned this time.

Here is a copy of the parachain current **xcm_executor config**:

```
pub type LocalAssetTransactor = CurrencyAdapter<
    Balances,
    IsConcrete<SelfLocation>,
    LocationToAccountId,
    AccountId,
    (),
>;

pub type TrustBackedAssetsConvertedConcreteId =
    assets_common::TrustBackedAssetsConvertedConcreteId<AssetsPalletLocation, Balance>;

pub type FungiblesTransactor = FungiblesAdapter<
    Assets,
    ConvertedRegisteredAssetId<
        AssetIdForTrustBackedAssets,
        Balance,
        AsAssetMultiLocation<AssetIdForTrustBackedAssets, AssetRegistry>,
        JustTry,
    >,
    LocationToAccountId,
    AccountId,
    NoChecking,
    PlaceholderAccount,
>;

pub type AssetTransactors = (LocalAssetTransactor, FungiblesTransactor);

pub type Barrier = TrailingSetTopicAsId<(
    TakeWeightCredit,
    AllowKnownQueryResponses<PolkadotXcm>,
    WithComputedOrigin<
        (
            AllowTopLevelPaidExecutionFrom<Everything>,
            AllowUnpaidExecutionFrom<ParentOrParentsExecutivePlurality>,
            AllowSubscriptionsFrom<ParentOrSiblings>,
        ),
        UniversalLocation,
        ConstU32<8>,
    >,
)>;    

pub type Traders = (
    FixedRateOfFungible<RUsdtPerSecond, ()>,
    FixedRateOfFungible<RUsdPerSecond, ()>,
    FixedRateOfFungible<RocPerSecond, ()>,
    UsingComponents<WeightToFee, SelfReserve, AccountId, Balances, ToAuthor<Runtime>>,
);
pub type Reserves = (NativeAsset, ReserveAssetsFrom<AssetHubLocation>);
pub type TrustedTeleporters = (xcm_builder::Case<AssetHubTrustedTeleporter>,);

pub struct XcmConfig;
impl xcm_executor::Config for XcmConfig {
    type Aliasers = Nothing;
    type AssetClaims = PolkadotXcm;
    type AssetExchanger = ();
    type AssetLocker = ();
    type AssetTransactor = AssetTransactors;
    type AssetTrap = PolkadotXcm;
    type Barrier = Barrier;
    type CallDispatcher = RuntimeCall;
    type FeeManager = ();
    type IsReserve = Reserves;
    type IsTeleporter = TrustedTeleporters;
    type MaxAssetsIntoHolding = MaxAssetsIntoHolding;
    type MessageExporter = ();
    type OriginConverter = XcmOriginToTransactDispatchOrigin;
    type PalletInstancesInfo = AllPalletsWithSystem;
    type ResponseHandler = PolkadotXcm;
    type RuntimeCall = RuntimeCall;
    type SafeCallFilter = Everything;
    type SubscriptionService = PolkadotXcm;
    type Trader = Traders;
    type UniversalAliases = Nothing;
    type UniversalLocation = UniversalLocation;
    type Weigher = FixedWeightBounds<UnitWeightCost, RuntimeCall, MaxInstructions>;
    type XcmSender = XcmRouter;
}
```

Any guidance on how to update the balance on the relaychain?

Comment: Quick feedback:


- The teleport case is expected to fail. General parachains are not meant to be trusted teleporters of the relay chain native asset.

- Can you give more details of the prcessing of the XCM message at Rococo side? What are the emitted events?

- If you are simply using polkadot_XCM pallet's `ReserveAssetTransfer` call from the parachain, it is not going to work. This call is meant to work when the origin chain is the reserve of the transferred asset.

Comment: @Iker Yeah, teleports not working makes sense. Also yes, I am using ReserveAssetTransfer call from the parachain. What would be the correct message that I need to execute on the parachain to transfer ROC back to the relaychain?

Comment: You will need to build a specific XCM program with the right instructions. Have a look at pallet xTokens in certain production parachains, this pallet have it implemented: https://github.com/open-web3-stack/open-runtime-module-library/blob/5c96d6bf12c5fc2aeac359f2297453ba63140927/xtokens/src/lib.rs#L240